# Ajuda - Conflito de Collation

Tags: sql, collation

Srs(as), boa tarde,

Poderiam me ajudar a identificar um problema?

Estou alterando uma PROC e ao testa-la está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Verifiquei as configurações de Collate das bases onde são feito os JOINS e ambas estão iguais:

*`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`*

A única diferença é que algumas colunas não possui definição de Collate
Ex.: `[Column_Name] [Data_Type] Collate NULL`

Fora isso nenhuma outra diferença.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Coloque a *tag* do banco de dados que está usando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dizes que as duas bases (bases de dados) têm a *collation*, o mais provável então é que as colunas que estás a utilizar na tua query, têm uma collation diferente do default da base de dados.

Em qualquer caso podes ajustar a tua instrução da seguinte forma para ultrapassar o problema:

```
SELECT ID
FROM tbl_a a
INNER JOIN tbl_b b
   ON a.campo1 = b.campo1 COLLATE database_default
WHERE a.campo2 = 'xpto'
```

OU

```
SELECT ID
FROM tbl_a a
INNER JOIN tbl_b b
   ON a.campo1 = b.campo1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE a.campo2 = 'xpto'
```

Comment: Bruno, obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente. Porem gostaria de entender o porque isso ocorreu, sendo que não existe Collate diferente do padrão estipulado na Base, quando é está como NULL.

Comment: @LuizMartinez, se isso resolveu o seu problema, você pode marcar essa resposta como a correta. Além de dar os devidos créditos a quem respondeu, você ainda ajuda outras pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida.